# Adding 2 columns of time series dataframes with different dates

Tags: pandas, dataframe, addition

I am looking to add two columns with different date range

```
column 1 = values with date index 2 Nov to 23 Nov
column 2 = values with date index 27 Oct  to 17 Nov

Resultant = addition of values in column 1 and column 2 of 27 Oct to 23 Nov
```

Sample pic attached

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrDwI.png)

1. Column 1 of dataframeA has data from 2 Nov to 23 Nov; each element
   has value 100
2. Column 2 of dataframe B has data from 27 Oct to 17 Nov; each element has value 200
3. Result will be data  sum of these columns with all date included.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example by posting a sample input dataframe with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

**df1:**

```
    Date        Value
0   2-11-2020   21.0
1   3-11-2020   4.0
2   4-11-2020   6.0
```

**df2:**

```
    Date        Value
0   3-11-2020   2.0
1   4-11-2020   2.0
2   5-11-2020   7.0
```

It should be:

```
df = df1.set_index('Date').add(df2.set_index('Date'), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

---

**df:**

```
    Date        Value
0   2-11-2020   21.0
1   3-11-2020   6.0
2   4-11-2020   8.0
3   5-11-2020   7.0
```